# How to setup IP spoofing in jmeter?

Tags: ip, jmeter, load-testing, spoofing

I am now load testing a website through jmeter from my machine. But I want a real world scenario , so can ip aliasing or ip spoofing be used by jmeter which will look like requests are being sent from different ip addresses.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it can, see property **Source IP address:**:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

Note that you must use HTTPClient implementations.

For a full tutorial, see :

- http://blog.milamberspace.net/index.php/2009/12/03/changer-ladresse-ip-source-dune-requete-http-lors-dun-test-avec-jmeter-549.html

Comment: hi, though I read ur answer, I didnt try it out, sorry for that, Will try it out and let you know. :)

Comment: I tried the solution given by you, but i am  getting error from Jmeter saying 
Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
what can be the reason?

Comment: I pinged both the IPs which I m using, and they are getting pinged.