# Jmeter: IP spoofing not working

Tags: jmeter, ip, spoofing

To test IP Spoofing I am following below steps:

1. Open `CMD` and do nslookup www.xyz.com.asdfg-staging.net
2. This will give the IP address , add this IP address at the bottom of hosts file.Here `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`
3. Open Jmeter and add this IP in Http Sample as shown below:

As instrcuted in links [How to setup IP spoofing in jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724989/how-to-setup-ip-spoofing-in-jmeter) and [send requests with multiple ip address to my application using apache-JMeter(IP Spoofing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602217/send-requests-with-multiple-ip-address-to-my-application-using-apache-jmeterip)
 4. Run the tests and I only see red errors in `View Results Tree` listener but I do not follows step #3 then there are only greens.

What I am expecting is "spoofed IP" i.e. the IP adress that I added in host file should be present in `Request` tab of `View Results Tree` listener.

What am I doing wrong here? The tutorials that shared above also asked to edit IPv4 properties , is that really mandatory to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: try the steps from here https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter. Yes, you must add the IP addresses to IPV4 Properties (Adavanced tab -> ADD button), then only you can specify those added IPs in IP Spoofing

Comment: If I put IP Address (in IPv4) there my internet on that machine would stop. No? Why?

Comment: We don't keep any random IP address in configuration. IP must represent the same subnet (like 192.168 or 10.10). Normally, router will allocate an IP address for your machine (using DHCP). In our configuration, we are allocating the IP(s) that is available with router manually.

Comment: Could you please put it in answer in detail?

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing after following the steps in given link? To explain the answer, it takes a lot of efforts where everything is already covered in the given link. please tell us the exact issue that you are facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IP Spoofing is done for the client side addresses. In your screenshot, you are trying to find the value of the spoofed IP in the HOST header which usually points to the actual server hostname and not the IP.

Scenario 1 with no values assigned in IPv4 field with test done against myhost.test.com

```
Request Headers:
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 162
Host: myhost.test.com
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_111)
```

Scenario 2 with Source Address field set to 10.1.153.90

```
Request Headers:
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 162
Host: myhost.test.com
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_111)
**X-LocalAddress: /10.1.153.90**
```

To me, it looks like you are trying to spoof your server IP to a specific IP provided by the service provider so that you hit only that like Akamai staging environment. In that case, setting your C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file with the assigned IP for your server (not the client) will work outside JMeter and is handled by the OS (not JMeter).

```
1.54.163.146 myhost.test.com
```

At the OS level, your OS will take care of sending requests addressed for myhost.test.com to the IP that you gave above in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file

To see the actual IP address, add a pre-processor (beanshell or equivalent) and add the below lines

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("myhost.test.com"); 
log.info("Address=" + address.getHostAddress());
```

If you want to measure your request time taken by this IP addresses, you can put it in a variable and add that in your sampler name

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("myhost.test.com"); 
log.info("Address=" + address.getHostAddress()); 
vars.put("addressused",  address.getHostAddress());
```

Then append ${addressused} to your samplername. It will measure the transaction based on samplername+ipaddress

Comment: Make sense to me. But is there a way, I can see that in Jmeter too that pages are getting served from IP provided in hosts file?

Comment: You can add a pre-processor with the below code which will print the actual IP like how the JVM resolves it which is in turn used by JMeter import java.net.InetAddress;

InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("myhost.test.com"); 
log.info("Address=" + address.getHostAddress());

Comment: where it is going to print, In logs? I am running in GUI mode, where I can see logs?I am hitting so many URLs in CSV file, I want logs for each URL in CSV file.

Comment: I've edited my post to include it in the sampler name so that you can measure it by IP returned